# Spring JPA | Search in Many to Many Relationship

Tags: mysql, orm, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have 2 tables `Book` and `Author` in a Many to Many Relationship using a candidate key table `author_book` which has primary keys of both `author` and `Book`.

I'm trying to get all books from a given author by `AUTHOR_ID`, maybe after if it works I'll try to do search by name

```
create table author_book(
    `AUTHOR_ID` INT,
    `BOOK_ID` INT
);
`
create table author(
    `AUTHOR_ID` int auto_increment,
    `FIRST_NAME` varchar(255),
    `LAST_NAME` varchar(255),
    `EMAIL` varchar(30),
    `CONTACT_NO` VARCHAR(10),
    primary key(AUTHOR_ID)
);
create table book(
    `BOOK_ID` int auto_increment,
    `TITLE` varchar(255),
    `SUBJECT` varchar(255),
    `PUBLISHED_YEAR` int,
    `ISBN` varchar(30),
    `QUANTITY` int,
    `SHELF_DETAILS` varchar(255),    
    `PUBLISHER_ID` int,
    `BOOK_COST` INT,
    primary key(BOOK_ID)
);
```

I decided I'll create `AUTHOR_NAME` using `CONCAT`

I tried this query for search by author_id

`@Query("select b from Books b where b.bookId in (select a.bookId from author_book a where a.author_id = :Id)")`

but I'm getting error that `author_book` is not mapped so do I need to create another entity for this class to perform any operations b/w these 2 class? I'm also not sure if nested queries work in JPQL, this was basically a hunch.

My `Books` Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Books implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="BOOK_ID")
    private int bookId;
    
    @Column(name="TITLE")
    private String title;
    
    @Column(name="SUBJECT")
    private String subject;
    
    @Column(name="PUBLISHED_YEAR")
    private int publishedYear;
    
    @Column(name="ISBN")
    private String isbn;
    
    @Column(name="QUANTITY")
    private int quantity;
    
    @Column(name="SHELF_DETAILS")
    private String shelfDetails;
    
    @Column(name="BOOK_COST")
    private int bookCost;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "author_book", 
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "BOOK_ID") }, 
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "AUTHOR_ID") })
    private Set<Authors> authors = new HashSet<Authors>();
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="PUBLISHER_ID")
    private Publishers publisher;

// getters and setters
}
```

My `Authors` Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="author")
public class Authors {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="AUTHOR_ID")
    private int authorId;
    
    @Column(name="FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column(name="LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    private String email;
    
    @Column(name="CONTACT_NO")
    private String contactNo;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "authors")
    private Set<Books> books = new HashSet<Books>();

//  Getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add mappedBy things in Authors Entity.

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="authors", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 private Set<Books> books = new HashSet<Books>();
```

Comment: Ah, I missed that when I copied, but this was already present in author Entity, sry